# howto use vpn only for traffic to that domain

Tags: networking, vpn

Many universities have a vpn for access to internal resource from the outside.
In my case, mine provides a vpn (Cisco Anyconnect) so that researchers can log into a cluster from home securely. Unfortunately the vpn connection reliability seems to be very poor. It's bad enough having my access to the machine on and off, but it also takes down my internet.

Is it possible to limit Cisco Anyconnect to only routing packets for a domain? What I want is only to use the vpn for connecting to the cluster, and for anything else, to go to my internet provider. Not only would this provide me with better service, but if everyone did it, I'll bet the reliability would go way up, it's quite possible they simply can't handle the load on the vpn.

In general, is it possible to configure multiple vpns for different requests?

Comment: What you’re trying to do is called a split tunnel. But from what I understand, you won’t be able to set this up on your end using AnyConnect; this has to be done server-side. However, you should be able to do this using OpenConnect. See this tutorial: [Split Tunnel with OpenConnect to AnyConnect VPN](https://gist.github.com/stefancocora/686bbce938f27ef72649a181e7bd0158)

Comment: @mpboden I don't understand how it's possible for this to be a server-side thing. They claim to have split tunneling working for windows by the way, I have not checked. But if my client chooses to use the VPN when I'm connecting to the collect, and does not for other networking, how would the server even know? This should be a client side thing.

Comment: I’m not very savvy with AnyConnect. So perhaps I mis-spoke. What I meant was I’m under the impression the IT manager from the server side needs to setup the config file for the client to use. I would contact your IT department at the university and inquire with them.